# Image Coversion From OpenScenegraph(OSG) To STL File Format

Tags: file-conversion, openscenegraph, stl-format

Can anyone guide me how do I convert `OSG (OpenSceneGraph)` file format image into `STL file format`. I tried to find ways by google searching but i didn't proper link for that.

I am working on `processing` where I need STL file.
So could you please help me get it by OSG file.

Answer (score 1):

osgDB is the library for read/write scene graphs in different formats, and there's an [OSG plugin](http://trac.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg//wiki/Support/UserGuides/Plugins) to read/write scene graphs to STL format.

First, you need to build OSG linking to [VRLM library](http://openvrml.org/), in which OSG depends to build de STL plugin. If you are using CMake, the keys are: OPENVRLM_INCLUDE_DIR, OPENVRLM_LIBRARY and OPENVRLM_LIBRARY_DEBUG. After a successfull build, you will find the builded plugin at bin\osgPlugins-3.0.1

Then, you only need to read the .osg scene graph and write the .stl scene graph. Something like this:

```
#include <osgDB/WriteFile>
#include <osgDB/ReadFile> 

...

osg::ref_ptr<osg::Node> node = osgDB::readNodeFile("node.osg");
osgDB::writeNodeFile(node, "node.stl");

...
```

osgDB will select STL plugin based on the file extension (.stl).

Answer (score 1):

`osgconv` which is a tool that is part of OpenSceneGraph should do the trick if you have the STL file format available, I don't know what the requirements for the stl plugin to build but `osgconv --formats` would tell you which formats are supported by your build of OSG, see [this reference](http://www.semirealgames.com/2009/04/osgconv-command-reference.html) or type in `osgconv --help` for all the options.

To convert just use `osgconv infile outfile.stl` this works with any format supported by OSG, reading and writing.